# can't link the javascript file in my html

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>js stalker</title>
   <script scr="stalker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>this is to test the basic js values</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the source file is in the same directory and the content of stalker.js

```
alert("the java script is linked");
```

Comment: its `src` not `scr`

Comment: You have a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled the `src`-attribute of the `<script>`-tag. The line should be `<script src="stalker.js"></script>`

Comment: i am so sorry i am beginner and i was stuck for more than 2 hours what's wrong in the code. thank u..

Comment: @DeepankarSingh no problem, it happens to all of us ^^